# Send "Sale" command to verifone vx520

Tags: verifone

I work on a project, where from PC I need to send Sale command to verifone vx520. Any documentation? How can this be done? What exactly I need to complete this task? Any documentation about this subject will help. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the documentation for you, good luck.
https://www.verifone.com/sites/default/files/VX520_Manual_English.pdf

Comment: I read all that documentation, page by page, letter by letter, nothing about the connectivity or send/receive amount from pc

Comment: If its not in the documentation for that phone it might not be a feature of that device.  Maybe you mean you need to know how to do from scratch the whole front end for an application to generate the signal to send the phone?  That is sort of beyond the scope of this website unfortunately, but specific problems can be addressed.

Comment: @easleyfixed - verifone vx520 is not a phone! :)

Comment: Ops I fixed one of my typos to say device but not the first one, but yeah I'm not sure where to point you as you need what might be proprietary information.

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) Initiating a connection from the server to the terminal is backward from 99% of use cases for terminals like these. It probably CAN be done, but I doubt you're going to find pre-built libraries to facilitate it.  2) Not sure what your use case is, but could you have the terminal poll the server?  3) As you are probably aware, Vx520s are end-of-life, so if a feature isn't already there, it won't be coming later, either. That also means if you have to conform to PCI or similar standards, you don't want to be using a 520 at all.